# Avoid to create new instance of activity after finish child activity

Tags: android, android-activity

There are several activities in my application. First is Launching activity (A) that create (startActivityWithResult) a dialog activity "First run wizard" (B) from that user can launch some settings activity (C). When user walk back from activity C (by back button) instead  of bringing back activity B (or destroy it completely and create it back with saveInstanceState) it first call onStart, onResume of original acitivity B then creates a new instance of activity B without any saveInstanceState. User see only that new instance, but old instances still present, consume memory and get onStart and onStop (even they are hidden). Now I have multiple instances of B and a new ones created after I back from activity C. I must close all instances of B before I can go back to A.
My question is: how to avoid create multiple instances of same instance B? I try to set **singleTop**, **singleTask** or **singleInstance** for B in manifest and it did't work. There are another ways to get activity C in my application so I do not want to change activity C. Currently I didn't set any flags while create activities B or C.

There are manifest file:

Activity A:

```
<activity
    android:name=".A"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:stateNotNeeded="true">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Activity B:

```
<activity
    android:name=".B"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:label="B"
    android:parentActivityName=".A"
    android:theme="@style/WizardDialog">
</activity>
```

Activity C:

```
<activity
    android:name=".C"
    android:label="C">
</activity>
```

There are WizardDialog theme for B (Activity A partially visible under B):

```
<style name="WizardDialog" parent="@style/AppDialogBasic">
    <item name="android:maxWidth">300dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">360dp</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateAlwaysHidden</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
  </style>
```

Also there is output of activities sysdump:

```
ACTIVITY MANAGER ACTIVITIES (dumpsys activity activities)
Display #0 (activities from top to bottom):
  Stack #1:
  mFullscreen=true
  mBounds=null
    Task id #88
    mFullscreen=true
    mBounds=null
    mMinWidth=-1
    mMinHeight=-1
    mLastNonFullscreenBounds=null
      TaskRecord{be4d271 #88 A=com.a.a U=0 StackId=1 sz=3}
      Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.a.a/.WaitingActivity }
        Hist #2: ActivityRecord{fd61815 u0 com.a.a/.SetupWizardActivity t88}
          Intent { cmp=com.a.a/.SetupWizardActivity }
      ProcessRecord{d21940e 17900:com.a.a/u0a79}
        Hist #1: ActivityRecord{f891058 u0 com.a.a/.SetupWizardActivity t88}
          Intent { cmp=com.a.a/.SetupWizardActivity }
      ProcessRecord{d21940e 17900:com.a.a/u0a79}
        Hist #0: ActivityRecord{e2bb06a u0 com.a.a/.WaitingActivity t88}
          Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.a.a/.WaitingActivity }
          ProcessRecord{d21940e 17900:com.a.a/u0a79}

    Running activities (most recent first):
      TaskRecord{be4d271 #88 A=com.a.a U=0 StackId=1 sz=3}
        Run #2: ActivityRecord{fd61815 u0 com.a.a/.SetupWizardActivity t88}
        Run #1: ActivityRecord{f891058 u0 com.a.a/.SetupWizardActivity t88}
        Run #0: ActivityRecord{e2bb06a u0 com.a.a/.WaitingActivity t88}

    mResumedActivity: ActivityRecord{fd61815 u0 com.a.a/.SetupWizardActivity t88}

  Stack #0:
  mFullscreen=true
  mBounds=null
    Task id #75
    mFullscreen=true
    mBounds=null
    mMinWidth=-1
    mMinHeight=-1
    mLastNonFullscreenBounds=null
      TaskRecord{cf23856 #75 I=com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity U=0 StackId=0 sz=1}
      Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000100 cmp=com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity }
        Hist #0: ActivityRecord{de71b57 u0 com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity t75}
          Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000100 cmp=com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity }
          ProcessRecord{bc76608 2088:com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/u0a20}

    Running activities (most recent first):
      TaskRecord{cf23856 #75 I=com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity U=0 StackId=0 sz=1}
        Run #0: ActivityRecord{de71b57 u0 com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity t75}

  mFocusedActivity: ActivityRecord{fd61815 u0 com.a.a/.SetupWizardActivity t88}
  mFocusedStack=ActivityStack{b84edc4 stackId=1, 1 tasks} mLastFocusedStack=ActivityStack{b84edc4 stackId=1, 1 tasks}
  mSleepTimeout=false
  mCurTaskIdForUser={0=88}
  mUserStackInFront={}
  mActivityContainers={0=ActivtyContainer{0}A, 1=ActivtyContainer{1}A}
  mLockTaskModeState=NONE mLockTaskPackages (userId:packages)=0:[]
  mLockTaskModeTasks[]
```

Answer (score 0):

So, extra instance of activity was created in A during **onStart**. I completely overlook that place. **onStart** of A was called because B is partially transparent dialog and when C destroyed A also bring to front. I fix this with flag:

```
firstStartWizardIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivityForResult(firstStartWizardIntent /* B */, DIALOG_FIRST_START_WIZARD);
```

and set **launchMode** for B back to **standard**.